# OpenTl auto update on telegram messages throws error CS0079 c#

Tags: c#, error-handling, compiler-errors

I recently tried to use the auto update example that is on the OpenTL quick start page, and just using the following basic example

```
await clientApi.UpdatesService.AutoReceiveUpdates += update =>
{
// Handle updates
 switch (update)
    {
        case TUpdates updates:
            break;
        case TUpdatesCombined updatesCombined:
            break;
        case TUpdateShort updateShort:
            break;
        case TUpdateShortChatMessage updateShortChatMessage:
            break;
        case TUpdateShortMessage updateShortMessage:
            break;
        case TUpdateShortSentMessage updateShortSentMessage:
            break;
        case TUpdatesTooLong updatesTooLong:
            break;
    }
};
```

It won't compile throwing this error :

> Error CS0079 The event 'IUpdatesService.AutoReceiveUpdates' can only appear to the left of += or -=

I put it into an async Task function, but I don't think thats the problem. I don't really know how to use an async event like that.
[link to the example](https://github.com/OpenTl/OpenTl.ClientApi/wiki/Quick-Start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have written it is wrong. It rather should be

```
clientApi.UpdatesService.AutoReceiveUpdates += async update => 
{
// Handle updates
 switch (update)
    {
```

Comment: Thanks, but now It's giving a warning that It's not using 'await' and will be executed synchronously, where should I put the await ?